# WebRatio - fill list with custom query

Tags: list, frameworks, fill

I just started to use WebRatio and I am facing a simple problem, with easy solution if I was not using this fabulous framework .... I was asked to do some sort of glosary app, and what I am trying to do right now is a simple index where appears all letters from A-Z and how many entries starting with each letter there are in my database, quite simple.

I aleady started a database with my entity: name, description and last_modified. I had been looking for some information on how to do this but I found nothing. So what I am trying to do is to fill a list with a custom query that I made (it works good on my sql editor) but I am not able to list the results in a WebRatio list. I tried to use a "query" object linked to a "simpleList" object but when I run the app it gives me error: "Expected at least one element .. inside " I would appreciate any help or resource that explains how to do this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't link the query unit with list because the list will make it's own database query. Instead you should specify outputs for query unit and write your custom style template for query unit to visualize the results as html. Or also (not recommended) you can link the results of query unit with a script unit and output desired html within a script unit.